# Django Rest Framework - How to use "UniqueTogetherValidator" if one of the fields is provided as a URL variable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Hello I have a model with a unique_together constraint but the serializer cant validate it because one of the fields is being passed as a variable in the URL:

How can I access the url variable int:pk inside the serializer for the "UniqueTogetherValidator" to work properly.

My model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='recipe_reviews', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='reviews', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    rating = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'post']
```

My url looks like this:

```
path('posts/<int:pk>/reviews/create/', ReviewCreateView.as_view()),
```

My view:

```
class ReviewCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ReviewCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # Grab post using URL Variable (pk) and save the review
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        serializer.save(post=post)
```

And my serializer:

```
class ReviewCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['user', 'post', 'rating', 'comment']
        validators = [
            serializers.UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Review.objects.all(),
                fields=['user', 'post']
            )
        ]
```

Since I'm not passing the post ID in the body of the request, I get the following error:

```
{
    "post": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Is there any way of creating my own field that grabs the information from the URL variable? (similarly how the HiddenField is grabbing the CurrentUser automatically)

I would really appreciate the help.
Thanks!

---

### **UPDATE:**

---

I tried overwriting the "create" method in my View as suggested by iklinac:

```
class ReviewCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ReviewCreateSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=kwargs['pk'])
        review = Review(user=self.request.user, post=post)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(review, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And my serializer looks like this:

```
class ReviewCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['user', 'post', 'rating', 'comment']

        validators = [
            serializers.UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Review.objects.all(),
                fields=['user', 'post']
            )
        ]
```

But I still get the following error:

```
{
    "post": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried what it says on that post but It doesn't seem to work. Ive updated my post with my new code following that link you sent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53172106/8283848 this should work

Comment: Thanks JPG this seems to be the simplest way of doing it